# Change from windows 7 to ubuntu 14. And doesnt work

Tags: tmp

I changed from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04 and after installation it loaded Windows.

From windows i selected Ubuntu as my default OS. Since, it only shows a message that says serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /. Selected I and then it says the disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present.

I installed Ubuntu using WUBI.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** you've probably used WUBI to install *and that's deprecated*.  Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) instead on how to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use Wubi any more. It was discontinued about 3 yrs or so ago. Instead, burn the Ubuntu ISO to a DVD or USB from within Windows and install Ubuntu by booting off it.

As you have installed Ubuntu using Wubi, uninstall it again in the same way, meaning uninstall it from Windows' Control Panel.

Now boot off the created USB or DVD and install Ubuntu from there using manual partitioning or the "Alongside Windows" option.

---

**EDIT:** To get back to Windows, try to open the GRUB2 (Ubuntu's boot loader) menu by pressing <kbd>↑Shift</kbd> during boot. If that doesn't work, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> when the error message is shown. It should reboot and take you to the boot menu.

If the Windows entry is shown in the menu, simply select and boot it. It may be hidden in something like "Other operating systems". If it isn't there, press <kbd>C</kbd> to drop to the GRUB shell. Now execute the following command:

```
chainload (hd0,0)+1
```

This will let GRUB load the first sector of the first partition of the primary disk, most likely where Windows is installed. If it doesn't work, use the command `ls` to get a list of partitions and try to chainload each of them using above command. If you manage to boot Windows, immediately uninstall Ubuntu using above described method, which should reinstate the Windows boot loader.

If all of this fails and you cannot get Windows back, boot a Windows (Vista or later) installation disk and run the Boot repair utility off it. This should reinstate the Windows boot loader.

Comment: How i go back to windows to do so? Since i selected ubuntu as default os it doesnt let me choose wich os to use it goes direct to the error message?

Comment: @FerdinandMiranda I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is deprecated so log in to Windows 7 uninstall Ubuntu which has been installed as a program and then create a bootable usb of Ubuntu 15.04 in windows with universal usb installer and restart. Select to load from the usb and you will have the option to install ubuntu along with Windows 7.

Comment: How i go back to windows to do so? Since i selected ubuntu as default os it doesnt let me choose wich os to use it goes direct to the error message?