# Go back to windows

Tags: system-installation, windows, tmpfs

How can I go back to Windows? I installed Ubuntu using wubi. Then I selected Ubuntu 14.04 as default os. Now I have to unistall it and install it from a cd or usb. The problem is that my pc starts directly on Ubuntu and shows the error message that says `/tmp not found` or not present.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: @JoKeR It's not a duplicate since he used Wubi to run Ubuntu with Windows. To remove Ubuntu, he needs to remove Wubi; Windows was always available.

Comment: @LDC3 he already asked a question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/636895/change-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu-14-and-doesnt-work like *thomasrutter* also mentioned seems like he cannot boot to any OS.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined at [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide):

> How do I uninstall Wubi?
>
> Run the uninstaller in "Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs" for Windows XP or lower or "Control Panel > Programs and Features" for Windows Vista or Windows 7. Alternatively, you can run: C:\ubuntu\Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe.`

Comment: It sounds like this user is also unable to boot into Windows

Comment: I think, first he should re-install and update grub so that he can gain access to window, after that he can follow this uninstall of  **WubiGuide**.